# Paraview error associated with definition of two sets of cell_data

Tags: paraview

I am trying to define two sets of cell data. When I define either one of them separately, no problem, if I define a second one (see below), then I get an error

```
# vtk DataFile Version 3.0
Increment 59 
ASCII
DATASET UNSTRUCTURED_GRID
POINTS 304 float
0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00
...
1.578900e-01 1.520210e-01 0.000000e+00
CELLS 544 2176
3      0      6     62 
...
3    303    300    302 
CELL_TYPES 544
5
5
...
2
CELL_DATA 544 
SCALARS Mat_Groups int 1
LOOKUP_TABLE default
1
1
1
...
CELL_DATA 544 
SCALARS COD float 1  <<<<<<<<<
LOOKUP_TABLE default
0
7.580314e-07
0
4.322103e-07
0
5.605113e-07
4.802304e-13
...
POINT_DATA    304
VECTORS Displacements float 
1.000000e-06 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 
...
```

Thanks

victor

Answer (score 0):

You should not specify twice the `CELL_DATA` anchor. Remove the second one and it should be ok.